# WPF TextBox IsReadOnly Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, multibinding, readonly-attribute

Below is `IMultiValueConverter` I have:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  int loggedId = (int)values[0];
  int createdId = (int)values[1];
  DateTime time = (DateTime)values[2];

  TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time);

  if (loggedId == createdId && span.TotalHours <12)
    return (bool)true;

  return (bool)false;
}
```

Based on it, I want to set property `IsReadOnly` of a Text box. However it does not work, it is always set to true.

```xml
<TextBox.IsReadOnly>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LoggedUserEnabledStyle}">
    <Binding Path="LoggedUser.ID" />
    <Binding Path="HandOverFormList/CreatorID" />
    <Binding Path="HandOverFormList/TimeOfCreation" />
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.IsReadOnly>
```

Converter returns correct values, as if I change `IsReadOnly` to `IsEnabled`, it works fine. Though, I use another convert to color code background depending on the value, so `IsEnabled` is not best choice.

Comment: Just like the standard WPF Textbox, IsReadOnly has effect only when IsEditable = true, but does not prevent the user from selecting values - it just makes the editable text box read-only. To completely prevent the control from selection you should use IsEnabled = false.

Comment: Does `Path="HandOverFormList/CreatorID"` actually work?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the converter? Set a break point at the `if` statement, and make sure all the local variables are as expected.

Comment: what is not working, are you still able to input in textbox? How did you verify it's not working, IsReadOnly is always true?

Comment: The converter works fine. As I've said, if I change <TextBox.IsReadOnly> to <TextBox.IsEnabled> it works fine, disables it when needed. The problem with IsReadOnly is that, even if it should prevent user from inputting data, they still can change them. It simply has no effect. If I do: <TextBox.IsReadOnly>True</TextBox.IsReadOnly> - it disables editing

Comment: Based on the information you provided, I don't see any reasons why it should not as expected. Could it be possible to extract the relevant part of your code and create a sample which reproduces your error and share it?